# Stackdriver missing CPU and Memory information on summary page for GKE container

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have two projects say `project1` and `project2`. I have a k8s cluster in each of them. Both of them were started using this https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/installing with `Try the new Stackdriver beta Monitoring and Logging experience` checked.

On the stackdriver console in `project1`, when I try to create a new chart in a dashboard, when selecting the `Resource Type` I can see an option called `GKE Continer`, however, I can't see this option in `project2`.

Moreover, in the summary page for `k8s beta`, I can't see the CPU Usage and memory usage.

Is there anything wrong with the setup?

[image]